# Error when trying to compile tccv document class example

Tags: errors, miktex, texmaker, two-column, cv

Downloaded the [tccv document class](http://dev.entidi.com/p/tccv/source/tree/master/) and tried to compile one of the bundled examples using TeXMaker and MikTeX on Windows. First error I received for scrart.cls not being found, so I found a copy of that and threw it in the folder with the tccv files, then I received a slew of errors:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \@BCOR already defined.
>   Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \@@BCOR already defined.
>   Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
>
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \@DIV already defined.
>   Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

and others. My troubleshooting knowledge in LaTeX is limited, I tried commenting out the lines where the errors were supposed to happen, but it didn't change anything, looks to be tied to `\end{document}`, so probably a compile time error.

The only thing I found online was [half a thread](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=24901) about the issue but I wasn't sure what to make of it. This can be reproduced from the examples in the latest version of the source.

Comment: Your `First error I received for scrart.cls` sounds for me that you have not installed KOMA-Script? With basik MiKTeX installed KOMA-Script is missing.  Open the package manager to install it.

Comment: I have it set to install missing packages automatically, do I still have to install it manually? I will try anyway,  thanks.

Comment: Okay, so what happened was I wasn't connected to the Internet when I first tried to compile the document. Them in turned on the internet, downloaded scrart.cls and turned it back off. Deleting that copy of scrart and letting miktex do its thing resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your given first error message `scrartcl.cls not being found` tells you that KOMA-Script (document class `scrartcl` is one part of it) is not installed on your computer. I guess you installed only basic MikTeX, that does not include KOMA-Script, as far as I know!

You have two possibilitys:

1. Install the complete MIKTeX, if you do not have an internet connection all the time you use MiKTeX or
2. make sure you have an activated internet connection and activate the "installing on the fly" mechanismn of MikTeX. Then MiKTeX is able to install without an actions of you the missing packages or document classes or ... That is only usefull if you always have a running internet connection!

I personaly prefer the complete installation. Then I can use LaTeX with or without internet connection ...